# Highlight the matching words in the result after comparing the input text with a string array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an input field to enter the input text and a button. I also have an array of predefined words. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xv3zk78p/1/)

```
var strArray = ["critical","normal","high","low","blood pressure","fracture"];
```

Assume the **input** text is

> "the patient is in critical condition and the blood pressure is very
> low"

Clicking on the Submit button should compare the input text with all the string in the array and find out the matching words and display the same text as output with the matched words highlighted in a certain color.

Expected **Output**

The same text with the matched words highlighted.

> "the patient is in **critical** condition and the **blood pressure** is very
> **low**"

Is there anyway to achieve this using javascript / jQuery ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a dynamic Regexp to ignore case and hit only full-word matches and [].forEach:

```
var r=["critical","normal","high","low","blood pressure","fracture"],
s="the patient is in critical condition and the blood pressure is very low";

// replace each keyword in r with a mark'd replacement:
r.forEach(function(a){ 
         s=s.split(RegExp("\\b"+a+"\\b","i")).join("<mark>"+a+"</mark>");  
});

// view s after replacements:
s; // == "the patient is in <mark>critical</mark> condition and the <mark>blood pressure</mark> is very <mark>low</mark>"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If possibile could you explain how the `s=s.split(RegExp("\\b"+a+"\\b","i")).join("<mark>"+a+"</mark>");` works?

Comment: split() turns a string into an array without the delimeter, while join() turns that array back into a string, using the orig text wrapped with HTML5 mark tags, which has the net-effect of simply wrapping the matches. The RexExp is used to specify boundaries around the match to avoid partial hits, and the "i" flag to ignore case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code..

```
var strArray = ["critical", "normal", "high", "low", "blood pressure", "fracture"];
$("input[type='submit']").on('click', function (es) {
    var tmp = [];
    var stmt = $("input[type='text']").val();
    var stmt_arry = stmt.split(" ");
    $.each(strArray, function (i, vals) {
        $.each(stmt_arry, function (j, sVal) {
            if (sVal == vals) {
                stmt_arry[j] = "<b>" + sVal + "</b>";
            }
        });
    });
    var req_stmt = stmt_arry.join(" ");
    $("#result").html(req_stmt);
});
```

Updated Fiddle..

https://jsfiddle.net/yeswanth/nye9skd7/

Comment: hi.. thanks for the answering. But your code did not highlight the word 'blood pressure' in the result.